# Stream group incoming sort events

Tags: java, events, java-stream

I have a series of events, each event contains a timestamp, device, serialnumber, and measurement.

```java
class Event {
    private String device;
    private String description;
    private String serialnumber;
    private Measurement measurement;
}

class Measurement {
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
    private int value;
}
```

I have a stream of these events, and I would like to aggregate them into a simpler structure, dropping the serial number, then group them by device, and then sorting the measurements by timestamp and value.

```
{device: "device_1", description: "first device", serialnumber: "1", measurement: { timestamp: 2022-04-23T18:20:22Z, value: 180}}
{device: "device_2", description: "second device", serialnumber: "2", measurement: { timestamp: 2022-04-23T18:20:28Z, value: 120}}
{device: "device_2", description: "second device", serialnumber: "2", measurement: { timestamp: 2022-04-23T18:20:20Z, value: 160}}
{device: "device_1", description: "first device", serialnumber: "1", measurement: { timestamp: 2022-04-23T18:20:22Z, value: 170}}
```

```
[
    {
        device: "device_1",
        description: "first device",
        measurements: [
            { timestamp: 2022-04-23T18:20:22Z, value: 170},
            { timestamp: 2022-04-23T18:20:22Z, value: 180}
        ]
    },
    {
        device: "device_2",
        description: "second device",
        measurements: [
            { timestamp: 2022-04-23T18:20:20Z, value: 160},
            { timestamp: 2022-04-23T18:20:28Z, value: 120}
        ]
    }
]
```

I've managed to get the required format by creating a "builder" class in which you can insert events that get then processed and added to the data members in the correct format/order.
However, I think it would be nicer to somehow achieve this on the fly without another extra class, but using the `groupingBy` and `toMap` (and other?) stream methods.

Comment: Should the relationship between your classes be one-to-one, not one-to-many?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come up with this solution assuming that for each device there cannot be multiple measurements with same timestamp and value.

I understand that this could be a limit, but since I cannot see any ways of sorting a subset collected with a Collectors, I've decided to use a TreeSet to store the grouped measurements so that they will be sorted according to their natural ordering.

```
class Event {
    private String device;
    private String description;
    private String serialnumber;
    private Measurement measurement;

    public Event(String device, String description, String serialnumber, Measurement measurement) {
        this.device = device;
        this.description = description;
        this.serialnumber = serialnumber;
        this.measurement = measurement;
    }

    //... getters and setters ...
}

class Measurement implements Comparable<Measurement> {
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
    private int value;

    public Measurement(LocalDateTime timestamp, int value) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.value = value;
    }

    //... getters and setters ...

    //Redefinition of the natural ordering by timestamp and value

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Measurement m) {
        Comparator<Measurement> cmp = Comparator.comparing(Measurement::getTimestamp).thenComparing(Measurement::getValue);
        return cmp.compare(this, m);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("%s - %d", timestamp, value);
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Event> dataSource = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                new Event("device_1", "first device", "1", new Measurement(LocalDateTime.parse("2022-04-23T18:20:22"), 180)),
                new Event("device_2", "second device", "2", new Measurement(LocalDateTime.parse("2022-04-23T18:20:28"), 120)),
                new Event("device_2", "second device", "2", new Measurement(LocalDateTime.parse("2022-04-23T18:20:20"), 160)),
                new Event("device_1", "first device", "1", new Measurement(LocalDateTime.parse("2022-04-23T18:20:22"), 170))));

        Map<String, TreeSet<Measurement>> map = dataSource.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Event::getDevice, Collectors.mapping(Event::getMeasurement, Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new))));

        for (String key: map.keySet()){
            System.out.printf("%s => %s%n", key, map.get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The only thing I'm still trying to add is the description field next to the device. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @picklepick does it mean that you wanna group by "device + description"? So, like joining the device and description with a separator string like ":" or ";"? Sadly, the groupingBy operation only allows you to group by a method of the element you're traversing via the stream. This means that you need to define a method getDevicePlusDescr() where you basically return the two fields joined so that the stream will group by it. The only code you'll need to change will be the Collectors.groupingBy(Event::getDevicePlusDescr, ...), besides the new getter implementation.

Comment: the description shouldn't be part of the sorting, it should just be included in the object and thus the final output.

Comment: Btw I've written the previous comment solely based on your example's data where it seems like that every device is paired with a fixed description and said description always appears the same on every same instance of device

Comment: @picklepick when you say in the object, what do you mean? As part of the hashmap key?

Comment: uhm, that's the difficulty I'm having, if you look at my example output the device isn't the key for the measurements, there are the device, description and a list of measurements. Not sure if I'm making sense, sorry!

Comment: Ok, but I don't think you wanna group by for all the Event's fields, definitely not measurement, otherwise there won't be any reason to collect different measurements by an Event's device. If you wanna group by an event, I think you need to identify the key fields to create the groups with (say device, description and serial number). Then, you can either return a value with the three fields joined or return a custom object (EventKey) composed with only the fields you want for the grouping by (still the same three fields).

Answer (score 2):

You could get a `Map<String, List<Measurement>>` using `groupingBy` if that is what you are looking for:

```
Map<String, List<Measurement>> result = 
        events.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Event::getDevice,
                         Collectors.mapping(Event::getMeasurement, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed what I'm trying, however, this would still include the serial number and doesn't respect the sorting order right? That's where I'm having issues putting the individual steps into one working stream?